# Oracle mysterious Unicode codepoint

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-8, oracle11g

While calling XMLTYPE() on a CLOB column which should contain a valid XML1.0 xml (the db encoding should be UTF-8), the following error message comes out (I am from Italy):

```
ORA-31011: Analisi XML non riuscita
ORA-19202: Errore durante l'elaborazione XML
LPX-00217: carattere non valido 15577023 (U+EDAFBF)
Error at line 240
ORA-06512: a "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: a line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Now this invalid character is given as **Unicode codepoint EDAFBF**. The problem is that according to Unicode spec (wikipedia), there are no codepoints beyond **10FFFF**. So what could this error mean?

Inspecting this CLOB with SQLDeveloper (and copying it to Notepad++ with encoding set to utf-8) does not reveal anything unusual beyond some strange characters which apparently came from the user browser when he copied text from a Microsoft Word document (but the CLOB, at least as copied from SQLDeveloper UI and exhibited by Notepad++ with UTF-8 encoding, seems to be a valid UTF-8 text).

Is there a way to reproduce this error populating Oracle directly (from SQLDeveloper or in some other way)? (contacting the end user to understand what he put exactly in the web form is problematic)

Comment: Do you see [the replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) when you view the CLOB - is that one of the strange characters?

Comment: @AlexPoole ok, but I have seen no standard with "EDAFBF". Besides, I noticed that the page/subpage info on the page you cite is incorrect (it refers to codepoints with 5 hexadecimal characters). And then (I add it in the question), how can I recreate teh error populating oracle directly (since it is problematic to contact the user to understand what input he put in, and then it might be that he does not even remember).

Comment: Yes, I realised that page was just showing the replacement character, which wasn't helpful; but your client/Notepad might be doing the same, while XMLType is stricter.

Comment: @AlexPoole answering your new comment, when I open it with SQLDeveloper (opening the xml, I don't see the rhombus with question mark, but just an empty square with a thin black border

Comment: Could the error message about U+EDAFBF be misleading, maybe? I don't see how it could have stored a code point that large in a CLOB field. It so happens that the byte sequence 0xED,0xAF,0xBF is a UTF-8 encoding of the surrogate U+DBFF, which is of doubtful validity and certainly not permitted in XML parsing. What do you get if you hex-dump the contents of the CLOB, maybe there's actually a bad UTF-8 sequence of this nature in there?

Comment: @bobince "Could the error message about U+EDAFBF be misleading, maybe?" - yes, I see now that the answer by Alex Poole suggests this is the case; and thank you also for your insight regarding U+DBFF.

Answer (score 7):

Not addressing the first part of the question, but you can reproduce it with a RAW value:

```
select xmltype('<dummy>'
  || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(cast('EDAFBF' as raw(6)))
  || '</dummy>')
from dual;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00217: invalid character 15577023 (U+EDAFBF)
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Just selecting the character:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(cast('EDAFBF' as raw(6)))
from dual;
```

... is displayed as a small square with an even smaller question mark inside it (I think) in SQL Developer for me (version 4.1), but that's just how it's choosing to render that; copying and pasting still gives [the replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) � since the codepoint is, as you say, invalid. XMLType is being stricter about the validity than CLOB. The `unistr()` function doesn't handle the value either, which isn't really a surprise.

(You don't need to cast the string to `raw(6)`, just `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('EDAFBF')` has the same effect; but doing it explicitly makes it a bit clearer what's going on, I think).

I don't see how that could have got into your file without some kind of corruption, possibly through a botched character set conversion I suppose. You could maybe use `dbms_lob.replace_fragment()` or similar to replace or remove that character, but of course there may be others you haven't hit yet, and at best you'd only be treating the symptoms rather than the cause.

Comment: thank you, this is very interesting to me, as soon as I have enough points I will upvote this answer.

Comment: the query gives different results on versions 11.2.0.1.0 and 11.2.0.4.0 (the corresponding dbs and instances have no apparent differences in configuration, as I was told). The error reported in the answer comes out on (SQLDeveloper connected to) the latter (the original error cited in the question was also seen there). On 11.2.0.1.0 I see instead "LPX-00285: surrogato Unicode 0xDBFF 0x3C non valido" (and in fact @bobince noticed, in his comment to the question, that 'EDAFBF' is UTF-8 encoding for the Unicode codepoint 0xDBFF)

Comment: @troubled_maker - I was using 11.2.0.3, so perhaps the behaviour changed in a patch release. I assume the DB character sets are the same, but not sure it should matter with UTF anyway. Passing DBFF in my test is valid for XMLType though: `select xmltype('<dummy>' || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2('DBFF') || '</dummy>') from dual;` gets `<dummy></dummy>`. So even more confusing.